# Postfix & Spamassassin - custom rule for return-path and from address not in same domain

Tags: postfix, spamassassin

Having a little trouble with Spamassasin identfying spam emails coming from a domain of mine.

The spam email is coming in from a return-path of `someone@spammer.com`, but the from field in the header is being set as `someone@mydomain.com`.

I've done a test by connecting to the smtp server, and setting my own from address (`someone@spammer.com`) and then using a different one in the DATA headers as `someone@mydomain.com`.

When i test it myself, spamassasin marks it as spam with the following variables:

```
X-Spam-Status: Yes, score=5.0 required=4.5 tests=ALL_TRUSTED,FROM_ADDR_WS,
HEADER_FROM_DIFFERENT_DOMAINS,MISSING_DATE,MISSING_HEADERS,MISSING_MID
```

However, on the original spam email I received externally, `HEADER_FROM_DIFFERENT_DOMAINS` does not get triggered!
In fact, the original spam email had a score of 0!

Any ideas why this could be? I have checked the original email and I can clearly see the return-path domain and the `From:`field are both different domains.

My goal is to mark any emails as spam if they have a different domain in the return-path to the from field, I thought that `HEADER_FROM_DIFFERENT_DOMAINS` rule would do this but it doesn't seem to have happened on the original spam email I got.

Any ideas where I'm going wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

First, you should really consider disabling accepting mail from yourdomain.com addresses without SASL authentication with something like

`smtpd_sender_restrictions =
 permit_mynetworks,
 permit_sasl_authenticated,
 reject_non_fqdn_sender,
 reject_unknown_sender_domain,
reject_unauthenticated_sender_login_mismatch,
permit`

The second thing is that what these spammer guys probably do is they feed you non-fqdn From: header (e.g. `From: mary`) that gets expanded on your system upon reception. Hence there's no domain mismatch, as there's no domain on a milter level in the `From:` field.